# Adding attachment to Jira via API

Tags: php, curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I am using Jira's API to add an attachment file to a case.  My issue is after my code attaches a file, and I go to the JIRA case to confirm, I see two things.  First, if it is an image, I can see a thumbnail of the image.  If I click it, though, I get an error saying "The requested content cannot be loaded.  Please try again."  Second, under the thumbnail, instead of showing the name of the file, it has the path that the file was originally uploaded from (id: c:/wamp/www/...."  Is there a reason this is happening? Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$header = array(
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
   'X-Atlassian-Token: no-check'
);
$attachmentPath = $this->get_file_uploads();
//$attachmentPath comes out to be something like:
//c:/wamp/www/mySite/web/system/files/my_folder/DSC_0344_3.JPG

$data = array('file'=>"@". $attachmentPath, 'filename'=>'DSC_0344_3.JPG');
$url= 'https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/20612/attachments/';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$ch_error = curl_error($ch);
```

Once the file gets added to Jira, when I log into jira, I can see the thumbnail but the title under the file is something like: c:/wamp/www/mySite/web/system/files/my_folder/DSC_0344_3.JPG instead of the file name.

thanks

Comment: I would say that your problem is with this line `$data = array('file'=>"@". $attachmentPath, 'filename'=>'DSC_0344_3.JPG');` somehow through the HTTP protocol it is sending wrong data. Do you have control over you Jira server ?

Comment: Another thing that I just noticed. Where are you using your `$header` variable? Maybe it should go here: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);` instead of `this->get_jira_headers()`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when copying over.  In my code I use properties.  I've corrected this typo.

Comment: No, I don't have access to the Jira servers.

Comment: And like I said, the attachment gets added.  It just cant be viewed or downloaded.  I think it's because instead of having a title for its link, its the long path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$data = array('file'=>"@". $attachmentPath . ';filename=DSC_0344_3.JPG');
```

It is an issue in PHP cURL <5.5.0 but > 5.2.10, see [JIRA API attachment names contain the whole paths of the posted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441028/jira-api-attachment-names-contain-the-whole-paths-of-the-posted-files)

When using PHP >= 5.5.0 it is better to switch to the `CURLFile` approach as also documented in that link.

```
$cfile = new CURLFile($attachmentPath);
$cfile->setPostFilename('DSC_0344_3.JPG');
$data = array('file'=>$cfile);
```

Comment: ah, I'll leave that one for you then :-)

Comment: I just put the direct link to the jira comment and the php bug tracker , http://stackoverflow.com/a/28124903/3933332

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  Unfortunately, I am using PHP 5.0.  The array Curl is expecting seems to be pretty touchy.  Even extra spaces will cause problems.  But, this worked!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anybody in the future: here's a function i wrote that works on php 7

```
function attachFileToIssue($issueURL, $attachmentURL) {
// issueURL will be something like this: http://{yourdomainforjira}.com/rest/api/2/issue/{key}/attachments 
// $attachmentURL will be real path to file (i.e. C:\hereswheremyfilelives\fileName.jpg) NOTE: Local paths ("./fileName.jpg") does not work!

$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck',
    'Content-type: multipart/form-data'
);

$cfile = new CURLFile($attachmentURL);
$cfile->setPostFilename(basename($attachmentURL));
$data = array("file" => $cfile);
curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $issueURL,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "{username}:{password}"
    )
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$ch_error = curl_error($ch);
if ($ch_error)
    echo "cURL Error: " . $ch_error;

curl_close($ch);
```

}